# Firebase angular many to many relation query

Tags: angularjs, firebase, many-to-many, firebase-realtime-database

I have a fairly simple json structure of groups and people and I am struggling to get/read a list of the group names for each person from firebase. This is what I tried. I spent a couple of days debugging unsuccessfully. Help much appreciated.

JSON:

```
{
"groups" : {
"one" : {
  "members" : {
    "-KLxjv9OnQB2l5Ohr-7I" : true
  },
  "name" : "group alpha"
},
"two" : {
  "members" : {
    "-KM4oXjftRZZ5DXYt4B2" : true
  },
  "name" : "group beta"
},
"three" : {
  "members" : {
    "-KM4oXjftRZZ5DXYt4B2" : true
  },
  "name" : "group gamma"
}
},
"persons" : {
"-KLxjv9OnQB2l5Ohr-7I" : {
  "groups" : {
    "one" : true
  },
  "personName" : "name1",
  "personTitle" : "title1"
},
"-KM4oXjftRZZ5DXYt4B2" : {
  "groups" : {
    "two" : true
  },
  "personName" : "name2",
  "personTitle" : "title2"
  }
 }
}
```

APP.JS:

```
$scope.personsGroup = function(personObj){
var baseRef = new Firebase("https://un-cms-13264.firebaseio.com/");
var personsRef = baseRef.child('persons');
var groupsRef = baseRef.child('groups');
var res=[];
    for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(personObj.groups).length;i++){
    var groupKey=Object.keys(personObj.groups)[i]
    res.push($firebaseArray(groupsRef.child(groupKey)));
    };
    return res;

}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="row" ng-repeat="person in persons">

<div class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3">{{person.personName}}</div>
<div class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 groupsList">
<ul><li ng-repeat="group in personsGroup(person)">{{group.name}}</li></ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: So you are trying to return the names of the groups one person is in?

Comment: What's the problem you're having? Also: if you can reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle/jsbin, people can play with it and see how things work (and possibly why it doesn't). You'll find that you get a lot more help that way.

Comment: yes @theblindprophet that's exactly my problem. I get blank entries and I am not getting the names of the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to attach `$firebaseArray` to a `$scope` variable:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://un-cms-13264.firebaseio.com/").child("persons").child(some-person).child("groups");
$scope.personsGroup = $firebaseArray(ref);

// When loaded
$scope.personsGroup.$loaded(function(data) {
     // can do something
}, function(error) {
     // error
});
```

How you determine `some-person` is up to you. You could query the `persons` tree and store all the persons or store it inside an array or object.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in personsGroup">{{ key }}</li>
</ul>
```

I would not advise `personGroup(person)` because `$firebaseArray` is an asynchronous call and I feel like it could be real jumpy. Be smart with it, you could also just get the entire `persons` tree in one call if you wanted:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://un-cms-13264.firebaseio.com/").child("persons");
$scope.persons = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

And do some iterating of that.

Comment: So now I get the group keys ("one","two" etc.) from person entity, but how do I tie it to the group.name from the groups entity ("group alpha","group beta" etc)?

Comment: Reference it: `ref = new Firebase("https://un-cms-13264.firebaseio.com/").child("groups").child(the-group);` then use can access `name`

Comment: Or you could just store the group name to begin with inside `persons` instead of `one`, `two`, etc